# Running airflow on Docker locally, "Import error, module not found"

Tags: python, docker, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to test a DAG locally, and have setup Airflow locally in Docker.

When I login using the web on localhost, I can see all of the example dags, however one dag I am trying to test appears at the top with the following error:

```
Broken DAG: Traceback
....
from airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake import S3ToSnowflakeOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.snowflake'
```

I have installed airflow locally using

```
pip3 install airflow
```

Is there a reason I can't see this module in locally running airflow on docker? My import statements are as follows (only the snowflake one errors out)

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake import S3ToSnowflakeOperator
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/_api/airflow/providers/snowflake/transfers/s3_to_snowflake/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you've installed an older version of Airflow without the provider you seek. The latest versions of Airflow uses the package name [apache-airflow](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/)

> "I'm attempting to test a DAG locally, and have setup Airflow locally in Docker."

This suggests to me you are attempting to re-create your hosted Airflow instance for testing purposes. Make sure to install whatever version of Airflow you trying to recreate. I would also suggest this [airflow in docker setup guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html). There are maintained images that might suit your purpose/make it easier.